# https://localhost:8080 is not working but http://localhost:8080 is working well

Tags: http, https, jboss

I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64 bit pc.JBOSS as my local pc server and i have a project which is using mysql as database and struts framework.I can easily access my project using

```
http://localhost:8080
```

but when I want to access my project using

```
https://localhost:8080
```

It shows an error.

The connection was interrupted
The connection to `127.0.0.1:8080` was interrupted while the page was loading.

I have also checked

```
$ sudo netstat -plntu | grep 8080
```

this command which output is

```
"tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5444/java"
```

If i kill this process,my project also killed.
and i also mentioned u that my 80 port is free also.

Can you tell me what is the problem is occured for which I cannot access my project in my local pc using `https`.

Advance Thanks for helping.

Comment: So SSL is all set on the server?

Comment: why need SSL certificate(self signed)?I am checking my project from my pc.Server = my pc....checking also from my pc browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL has to be on a different port. Here is the breakdown:

```
http:// watched on port, typically 80
https:// watched on a different port, typically 443
```

You need to RUN SSL on a different port.

```
Listen 8081
```

SSL VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
   # SSL Cert info here
   ....
</VirtualHost>
```

## > service httpd restart